# Compress Image as Byte Array

Tags: java, spring, image, jpa

After a while and after a stresstest of my database and it's REST Api the following Problem occurred.

We save images as **byte array in an Mysql Database via JPA/Hibernate** annotated like this:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "MEDIUMBLOB")
private byte[] photo;
```

Works as it should except when there are much high quality images and I want to retrieve all of them. Then the **Response takes too long** and event **Postman gets stuck**.

So I am **searching for a solution** to make those **byte Arrays smaller**.
Is there a way to **compress the image as byte array?** 
Or would another approach be better, **maybe paging** (Not my the best approach in my opinion for the task we have to solve)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean "compress"?

Comment: ah yes, corrected it

Comment: if image quality doesn't matter: compress the image before saving it by using e.g. Imagemagick

Comment: that's the question, how to I compress a byte array

Comment: you can pipe the byte array through a ZipOutputStream to compress it, but you'll have to uncompress it again on reading. So perhaps no performance gain

Comment: If you're storing images as their on-disk files (jpeg, png, tiff or whatever) then they are already compressed and you will just burn CPU cycles trying to get more compression. Better to change your API to ask for the available images then query them one at a time, displaying to the user as they arrive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the problem you face is that you read many images in the same query and that they take too much memory, leading to garbage collection and other problems. Compressing the images would not help as you will want to decompress them again before returning them to the client, plus most image formats are already compressed.

You could look into [streaming](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-streaming) instead, where you don't read all the matching images from the database into memory, but process them one at a time. Make sure that you stream the data you send to the client as well. If you get it right you can keep the memory usage down and you can send the first image to the client before you have read the others, reducing the time to first byte and making the response appear quick.

Alternatively do as one of the comments suggested and read the meta data first, then read the full image data for one image at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If the images are in JPEG there is photo quality compression at every level desired: high compression & low quality to the reversed. You could/should restrict image sizes (width and height). See ImageIO's ImageWriter and quality settings.

For BLOBs you should add:

```
@Lob
@Column(columnDefinition = "MEDIUMBLOB")
private byte[] photo;
```

It may be the case that it is better to have the image field in its own database table, so the original table is queried much faster.

As mentioned one could also store the images on the file system, maybe under a generated unique ID:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
String fileName = uuid.toString() + ".jpg";
```

In general using a `byte[]` field or local object is suboptimal, as it unnecessarily charges the server with memory. Immediately reading and writing to the response is better - outside JPA. Maybe a native query if you want things in the database.

Answer (score 0):

It's been 4 years and noone actually answered this question.

This is how to do it using the "Thumbnails"-Library (net.coobird.thumbnailator).

```
public static byte[] compress(byte[] binaryData, double scale, double quality) {
    if (binaryData != null) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Thumbnails.of(new ByteArrayInputStream(binaryData)).scale(scale).outputQuality(quality)
                .toOutputStream(baos);
            return baos.toByteArray();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // handle Exceptions
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```